# Entity Framework - Two Navigation Properties, One Key?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I've spent a few hours trying to google an answer to this, but I've come up with nothing.  I'm hoping it's just that I don't know how to phrase this and not a technical limitation.

I'm using Entity Framework Code-First (v5), and I'm trying to create a model which has two navigation properties sharing a single foreign key.  Obviously this foreign key could not exist in the database, because it could not point to both of the child tables.  Is EF able to work around this and still figure out what I want using custom mapping or annotations?

Example:

```
public class Parent {
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string EntityType { get; set; }
  public int EntityId { get; set; }
  // Additional properties

  [SomeSortOfAttributeICanPutHereToIndicateThisShouldUse("EntityId")] //?
  public virtual Child1 { get; }
  [SomeSortOfAttributeICanPutHereToIndicateThisShouldUse("EntityId")] //?
  public virtual Child2 { get; }
}

public class Child1 {
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Prop1 { get; set; }
}

public class Child2 {
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Prop2 { get; set; }
}

public Database : DbContext {
  public DbSet<Parent> Parents { get; set; }
  public DbSet<Child1> Children1 { get; set; }
  public DbSet<Child2> Children2 { get; set; }
}

var db = new Database();
var child1prop = db.Parents.First(p => p.EntityType == "Child1").Child1.Prop1;
var child2prop = db.Parents.First(p => p.EntityType == "Child2").Child2.Prop2;
```

Is what I'm trying to do even possible with Entity Framework, or am I wasting my time?

Comment: I think what you're looking fore is a Table Per Type (TPT) Inheritance. Read more about it here: http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/28/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt.aspx
Edit: I'll elaborate. If your Child1 object and your Child2 object have the same foreign key, I guess that they should have the same base class (let's call it ChildBase). If you let the Child property of the Parent be of type ChildBase, you should have what you wanted

Comment: Do `Child1` and `Child2` have many similarities? Or, would it make sense to derive both from one base class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is not possible. This sounds like trying to set to FK constraint from parent.cid to child1.cid and from parent.cid to child2.cid.

I just test: this seems possible (?!!#!):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[parent](
    [pid] [int] NOT NULL,
    [cid] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_parent] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [pid] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[parent]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_parent_child1] FOREIGN KEY([cid])
REFERENCES [dbo].[child1] ([cid])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[parent] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_parent_child1]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[parent]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_parent_child2] FOREIGN KEY([cid])
REFERENCES [dbo].[child2] ([cid])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[parent] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_parent_child2]
GO
```

**BUT:**

this means that when you set a value to parent.cid you must have a line in both child1 and child2.

Imho, this leads to schizophrenia.

Facing the same problem, I resign to have two FKs.

Another option is inheritance:

```
class base {
    int id {get; set;}
}

class child1 : base {
}

class child2 : base {
}
```

And then configure a TPT. This will leads to three tables for child1 and child2.

In your parent you can the have a property of type base. Then up to you to handle this property as child1 or child2.

hoping this helps

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine that a better way of handling this would be to have a collection of children on the Parent entity? It's a simple 1 to many relationship.

The parent class would contain a collection of children and the children would have a reference to its parent, then the parent could have x number of children as opposed to only two.

```
public class Parent {
  public int Id { get; set; }
  // Additional properties

  public virtual List<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Child {
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Prop1 { get; set; }

  public int ParentId { get; set; }
  public Parent Parent { get; set; }
}

public Database : DbContext {
  public DbSet<Parent> Parents { get; set; }
  public DbSet<Child> Children { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This wouldn't really help me, because the children are of completely different types, and I can't make them share a common ancestor via inheritance.

Comment: Should they not have different tables in that case?